# how to make a program that shows metadata while it's playing internet radio

Tags: audio-streaming, vlc

I want to make a command line tool that shows metadata like the music title and musician's name while it plays audio streaming such like internet radio.

When it comes to programming, I know next to nothing about audio streaming and `d-bus`.`Ruby` and `c/c++` are only languages I can use at the moment. It is more convenient to me if I can program using `shell script` or `ruby`.

Now I'm trying using [VLC](http://www.videolan.org) as the first challenge.

At first I tried [VLC command line tool(cvlc)](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Command_line/), but it didn't seem to give any options to what I wanted to do.
Then I knew there are some VLC APIs according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player#API). But I'm confused about what to do next.
Which API should I use? Or are there any recommendations to start this challenge?

I'm not stick to VLC. I'm using it everyday for listening to internet radio.That's the reason I chose it and there is no other intent.

OS: ubuntu 15.04

VLC version: 2.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also asked this issue [here](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/20204/vlc%E3%82%82%E3%81%97%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AF%E4%BB%96%E3%81%AE%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%AA%E7%AD%89%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%82%AA%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9F%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E8%A6%96%E8%81%B4%E4%B8%AD%E3%81%AB%E3%83%A1%E3%82%BF%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF-%E6%9B%B2%E3%81%AE%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%83%AB%E7%AD%89-%E3%82%92%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A0%E3%82%92%E4%BD%9C%E3%82%8A%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84) and got the solution.

If I want to listen to one of [Digitally imported](http://www.di.fm/) programs and log the metadata, this one liner can do that:

```
$ mplayer http://pub1.di.fm:80/di_melodicprogressive_aac?3d3d2d82969e89c2ca1fc2a7 >/dev/null 2>&1 | mplayer -slave -playlist http://pub1.di.fm:80/di_melodicprogressive_aac?3d3d2d82969e89c2ca1fc2a7
Resolving pub1.di.fm for AF_INET6...
Couldn't resolve name for AF_INET6: pub1.di.fm
Resolving pub1.di.fm for AF_INET...
Connecting to server pub1.di.fm[70.42.73.176]: 80...
Name   : DI - Melodic Progressive
Genre  : Electronic Melodic Progressive
Website: http://www.di.fm
Public : no
Bitrate: 64kbit/s

ICY Info: StreamTitle='Jav3x - Destiny';StreamUrl='';
```

(The URI this example uses may be changed.)